# Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.dialogflow.com:443

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've been using Dialogflow as the conversational agent for a chatbot. It was working totally fine until today. I keep getting the below error in between the chat. I see that there is an uncertainty in the dialogflow response, it does not give the error always but still **returns error multiple times** in the chat.  Can someone please provide a solution for this?

```
(node:29313) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: **Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN api.dialogflow.com:443**
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at errnoException (dns.js:55:15)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
```

Comment: Are u calling any external service/URL . If yes, is billing enabled?

Comment: Not calling any external service / URL